# How to get values from entry box with tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I want to take the values from the entry box that opens and have them become the values in `crop1`. I'm new to tkinter and programming so I'm not sure on how to get the values into the function. Sorry for two questions in a short period of time, this is my last one for today.

```
    from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageFilter, ImageEnhance

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        master.wm_title("Image examples")
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()
        master.bind('s', self.sharpen)
        master.bind('b', self.brighten)
        master.bind('d', self.darken)
        master.bind('B', self.blur)
        master.bind('r', self.rotate)
        master.bind('I', self.brighten)
        master.bind('c', self.cool)
        master.bind('w', self.warm)
        master.bind('<BackSpace>', self.undo)

def createWidgets(self):
    self.img = Image.open("lineage.jpg")
    self.photo1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img.convert("RGB"))
    self.label1 = Label(self, image=self.photo1)
    self.label1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, rowspan=10)

    self.photo2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img.convert("RGB"))
    self.label2 = Label(self, image=self.photo2)
    self.label2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, rowspan=10)

    button1 = Button(self, text="Brighten", command=self.brighten)
    button1.grid(row=0, column= 2)
    button2 = Button(self, text="Darken", command=self.darken)
    button2.grid(row=1, column= 2, sticky=N)
    button3 = Button(self, text="Warm", command=self.warm)
    button3.grid(row=2, column= 2, sticky = N)
    button4 = Button(self, text="Cool", command=self.cool)
    button4.grid(row=3, column= 2, sticky = N)
    button5 = Button(self, text="Sharpen", command=self.sharpen)
    button5.grid(row=4, column= 2, sticky = N)
    button6 = Button(self, text="Blur", command=self.blur)
    button6.grid(row=5, column= 2, sticky = N)
    button7 = Button(self, text="Rotate", command=self.rotate)
    button7.grid(row=6, column= 2, sticky = N)
    button8 = Button(self, text="Crop", command=self.crop)
    button8.grid(row=7, column= 2, sticky = N)
    button9 = Button(self, text="W/B Levels", command=self.brighten)
    button9.grid(row=8, column= 2, sticky = N)
    button10 = Button(self, text="Undo", command=self.undo)
    button10.grid(row=9, column= 2, sticky = N)



def brighten(self, event = None):
    img2 = self.img.point(lambda p: p * 1.9)
    self.photo2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)
    self.label2 = Label(self, image=self.photo2)
    self.label2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, rowspan=10)

def darken(self, event = None):
    img2 = self.img.point(lambda p: p * 0.5)
    self.photo2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)
    self.label2 = Label(self, image=self.photo2)
    self.label2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, rowspan=10)

def warm(self, event = None):
    img = Image.open("lineage.jpg").convert("RGB")
    (w, h) = (img.size[0], img.size[1])
    img2 = img.copy()
    pixels = img2.load()
    for x in range(w):
        for y in range(h):
            (r, g, b) = pixels[x,y]
            r = int(r*1.3)
            pixels[x,y] = (r, g, b)
    self.photo2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)
    self.label2 = Label(self, image=self.photo2)
    self.label2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, rowspan=10)

def cool(self, event = None):
    img = Image.open("lineage.jpg").convert("RGB")
    (w, h) = (img.size[0], img.size[1])
    img2 = img.copy()
    pixels = img2.load()
    for x in range(w):
        for y in range(h):
            (r, g, b) = pixels[x,y]
            r = int(r/1.3)
            pixels[x,y] = (r, g, b)
    self.photo2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)
    self.label2 = Label(self, image=self.photo2)
    self.label2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, rowspan=10)

def sharpen(self, event = None):
    img2 = self.img.filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN)
    self.photo2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)
    self.label2 = Label(self, image=self.photo2)
    self.label2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, rowspan=10)

def blur(self, event = None):
    img2 = self.img.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
    self.photo2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)
    self.label2 = Label(self, image=self.photo2)
    self.label2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, rowspan=10)

def rotate(self, event = None):
    img2 = self.img.rotate(270)
    self.photo2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)
    self.label2 = Label(self, image=self.photo2)
    self.label2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, rowspan=10)

def undo(self, event = None):
    img2 = self.img
    self.photo2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)
    self.label2 = Label(self, image=self.photo2)
    self.label2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, rowspan=10)



def crop(self):
    self.root = Tk()
    self.root.wm_title("Insert Coords")

    self.x0 = Entry(self.root)
    self.x0.grid()

    self.x1 = Entry(self.root)
    self.x1.grid()

    self.y0 = Entry(self.root)
    self.y0.grid()

    self.y1 = Entry(self.root)
    self.y1.grid()

    Button(self.root, text="Crop", command=self.close_crop).grid()

def close_crop(self):        
    self.crop1(self.x0.get(), self.x1.get(), self.y0.get(), self.y1.get())
    self.root.destroy()                

def crop1(self, x0, x1, y0, y1):
    print x0, x1, y0, y1
    img = Image.open("lineage.jpg").convert("RGB")
    (w, h) = (img.size[0], img.size[1])
    img2 = self.img
    img2 = img2.crop((self.x0,self.x1,self.y0,self.y1))
    self.photo2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)
    self.label2 = Label(self, image=self.photo2)
    self.label2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, rowspan=10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably a nicer way to do it, but this works. Add a button, and when that button is pressed get the input from the text entries and pass them to the crop function.

```
def crop(self):
    self.root = Tk()
    self.root.wm_title("Insert Coords")

    self.x0 = Entry(self.root)
    self.x0.grid()

    self.x1 = Entry(self.root)
    self.x1.grid()

    self.y0 = Entry(self.root)
    self.y0.grid()

    self.y1 = Entry(self.root)
    self.y1.grid()

    Button(self.root, text="Crop", command=self.close_crop).grid()

def close_crop(self):        
    self.crop1(self.x0.get(), self.x1.get(), self.y0.get(), self.y1.get())
    self.root.destroy()                

def crop1(self, x0, x1, y0, y1):
    print x0, x1, y0, y1
```

Comment: If you were to run the code, a window with four entry boxes opens when you click the crop button. What I'd like to do is get the information from those entry boxes and use them in the crop1 function. Could you expand on what you mean with the get(). I'm having a little trouble following.

Comment: can you please take a look at my updated code and see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `img2 = img2.crop((self.x0,self.x1,self.y0,self.y1))` is a problem line. Don't use `self.x0`, just use `x0`. Also keep in mind that `x0`, `x1`... are strings and not integers, so you will need to convert and perform the necessary validation.

Comment: I've got 'img2 = img2.crop((int(x0),int(x1),int(y0),int(y1)))' now, seems to work but no matter what I put in as the values it just makes the image disappear rather than cropping it